# Displaying Metarunner parameters for build steps

Tags: teamcity

I've created a metarunner in TeamCity, but I can't figure out how to display information from it on the list of build steps, which leads to several identical rows.  Other (built-in) runners have the ability to display some basic information to help clarify what the step is doing.  For example, in the image below, I have:

1. A metarunner with no description
2. The built-in Command Line task, **with a "Command" displayed**
3. Five instances of the same metarunner with different parameters, which all look the same.
4. The built-in SMB Upload task, **with a "Target SMB share" displayed**

[image: TeamCity build with metarunner steps]

One parameter from the "Copy config" metarunner looks like:

```
<param name="FileName" spec="text display='normal' label='File Name' description='Name of the file to be copied'" />
```

Is this something that can be edited via the metarunner XML?  Or is this a feature that's only available to built-in runners?

Answer (score 0):

I see `parameters/param` tags before the `build-runners/runner` section containing `parameters/param` (the latter being inputs to the wrapped runner, I guess).  The former allow editable inputs.  I am new so I feel uncomfortable with the multiple inheritance.  I would rather see the parameters configuration from the runner to show up in the Parameters section of the build.  I would also prefer if the runner could configure the artifact mapping as well.  So far I am going to configure parameters in the root project separately from my custom runner.  I did not look at custom plugins.

https://github.com/endjin/NewRelicDeploymentNotifierMetaRunner/blob/master/Solutions/SimpleRunner/server/metaRunners/MRPLUGIN_NewRelicDeploymentNotifier.xml

I figured I do not have to HTML-escape special characters in the runner's custom script, I could use the `CDATA` marker-wrapped clear text of the script as the `param` tag's text.

```
    <build-runners>
      <runner name="Run my runner" type="simpleRunner">
        <parameters>
          <param name="use.custom.script" value="true" />
          <param name="script.content"><![CDATA[@echo on
if not exist %env.CYGBINSLASH%python2.7.exe (
  powershell "$r = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $r.DownloadFile('%env.scriptweb%fixcygwin.bat', 'fixcygwin.bat')"
  call fixcygwin.bat /f
) 1>&2

@rem CMD.EXE would destroy leading double quotes in continuation lines, so sticking white space.
%env.CYGBINSLASH%bash -exc '^
 if [[ "${my_param}" != "true" ]] ; then ^
     exit; ^
 fi; ^
 /usr/bin/curl -o myscript.sh "${MY_SCRIPT}"; ^
 source myscript.sh "PROJ_%Project%" "%Project%/%Project%.csproj"; ^
' 1>&2]]></param>
          <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
        </parameters>
      </runner>
    </build-runners>
```

Comment: I’m sorry, but I can’t tell what you’re trying to demonstrate here.  What part of this changes the display of the metarunner?

Comment: I was aiming at "Is this something that can be edited via the metarunner XML" but I figured the run-time parameters have a chance of better reuse and coupling with agents if they reside in the build configuration or the build configuration template.